# Anylogic ports alternate use (?)

Tags: anylogic

after doing a few models using the predefined libraries, I'm building a model from scratch. In this model, I need a few different agents exchanging information between them, and I made it possible using  Dynamic Variables and making them visible from the upper agent. Connectors will join the blocks.  In picture one example of what I did and what I meant.

[image: Agent Example]

Since I've much info to exchange, I made one variable for inputs and one for output, using the "Array" option and using proper dimensions.
I was wondering if I could make them look cleaner and to have a better functionality, using ports. I saw them connecting to already existing library components, but never in an agent made from scratch. In the documentation I read that I could use the commands "port.send(obj)" and "port.receive(obj)" but I couldn't do anything working.
So my question is: is it possible to use ports to send objects via code (maybe agents, or dynamic variable or whatever) between agents? If yes, how to trigger the receiving action in the destination agent?
Thanks a lot in advance!
P

Comment: I recommend using Agent link connections for message passing, if you are at a beginner-to-medium skill level. After that, use custom msg passing but no need for ports, imo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood how to do what I had in mind.
Ports are capable of both sending and receiving data with just one connector. No more subsequent blocks are needed as suggested by @Artem, but his answer gave me the correct suggestion to find my own solution.

When ports exchange messages between them, when they receive it they call it "msg"; so "msg" could be fed to functions or it can be used to address inner fields (ie: msg.custom_field).

To use ports at it fullest, a low-level use detail should be achieved by enabling developer mode. To do so, follow the direction:
Tool -> Preferences -> Development -> Library developer mode.
Selecting this voice, now ports have those new voices when clicked on:

[image: port developer menus]

Ports now can be configured with the "in" and "out" message type (if needed they can be also different), and it is possible to associate a callback function when the port receives or sends a message.
For example, in figure 1, I set a "doSomething" function that takes the received message class and does something on it.

To send a message it should be used the "port.send(something)" code and the OnSend function will be taken into account before sending.

It is also possible to create custom ports inheriting the port class type, but I didn't push myself so deep in the white rabbit hole, sorry.

[image: Blocks connected by ports]

In figure 2, there is a small testbed I created with (working) ports. I hope that this little guide could help you all guys, even if this kind of use is just for very specific needing.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can add a port to your object or even create a custom port type as described [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/interaction/defining-custom-port-classes.html#custom-port-classes). However in order to send message to / from ports the message has to extend an **Agent** and ports have to be connected via a connector. The implementation pattern is:

1. Inside Sender agent: have an **Enter** block connected to a port
2. Inside Receiver agent: have a port connected to an **Exit** block
3. in Main agent: connect Sender port to Receiver port
4. Inside Sender: create a `msg` agent and use `enter.take(msg)`
5. The above will execute: Enter -> Sender port -> Receiver port -> Exit
6. Perform some action in `on Exit` property of **Exit** block in Receiver

Comment: I created a "Msg" agent with all parameter I wish to send.

I configured both Receiver and Sender as you told.
In both blocks I put a "msg" agent I will use as temporary variable and I configured both Enter and Exit blocks to work with "Msg" agent type.

I understood the that with enter.take(msg) I will be able to send my variable, but how to receive it from the exit block?

Regarding the point 6, is there something like exit.get(msg)? 
Writing this something in OnExit callback in the exit block, will I execute the code as soon something goet thoward exit?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at [Exit](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/exit.html#exit) docs, basically, there is an `On exit` action with `agent` parameter. In this case that `agent` is going to be the msg you sent via `enter.take(msg)` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Artem. I managed to do it! I wish to ask you a last further question: I tried to connect both `enter` and `exit` blocks to the same port but Anylogic gives me an error, saying that one `OutPort` can only be connected to an `InPort`.
In your experience is it possible to send and receive an agent through a single port? Still thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately using the same port for in and out isn't possible. The little secret of AnyLogic is that the ports are just visual markup, in the background it effectively connects **Enter** to **Exit** skipping all the ports. Hence, just like you can't connect **Enter** to **Enter** you can't use one ports both as `InPort` and `OutPort`.